# python-ldap change unicodePwd issue

Tags: active-directory, ldap, python-ldap

I am already managing different user`s AD attrs with code:

```
l = ldap.initialize('ldap://172.25.1.2')        
    l.simple_bind_s(admin_dn, admin_pw)

    user_dn="dn_here"
    change_attr = [(ldap.MOD_REPLACE, 'attr_to_change', new_value)]

    l.modify_s(user_dn,change_attr)
    l.unbind_s()
```

And it worked for all nessesary attrubutes, except unicodePwd.
After looking for a solution, I`ve found that unicodePwd should be changed using ldaps connection and port 636 
([Python+LDAP+SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716562/pythonldapssl)).
So I had tried to use that example:

```
    ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER)
    l = ldap.initialize('ldaps://172.25.1.2:636')
    l.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
    l.set_option(ldap.OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)
    l.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS,ldap.OPT_X_TLS_DEMAND)
    l.set_option( ldap.OPT_X_TLS_DEMAND, True )
    l.set_option( ldap.OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 255 )
    l.simple_bind_s(admin_dn, admin_pw)
    #change unicodePwdCOde here
    l.unbind_s()
```

but got an error:

```
ldap.SERVER_DOWN: {'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server"}
```

Should it have any solution in my code, or it should be fixed from AD server config?
Thanks for any help.
Sry for grammar mistakes.

Comment: Does your Active Directory have SSL enabled? Have you tried telnet-ing to port 636?

Comment: I will check it at monday while meeting our AD owner)

Answer (score 2):

I have answered this with example code (for encoding of unicodePwd), here:
[unicodePwd Attribute in AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68927680/unicodepwd-attribute-in-ad/72317853#72317853)

The gist of the answer is;

1. You have to use ldaps (ssl encryption)
2. You have to encode the password