# ldap authentication using only certificates

Tags: python, ldap, client-certificates

Is it possible to do LDAPS authentication using client certificates? if so/how?

I found the below but it still uses a bind method using user and password.

[Python+LDAP+SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716562/pythonldapssl)

I don't want to use user and password.  Currently using LDAPS from python to AD DC via port 3269.

It seems python-ldap always require user and password? are there alternative libraries/languages/toolsets/apis that do support client certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDAP standards defines a specific operation to authenticate a user based on the underlying transport security layer (TLS): the LDAP SASL EXTERNAL BIND.

When the connection is secured by TLS and the server was configured to require client authentication, then when the client sends a BIND SASL EXTERNAL request, the server retrieves the client identity and tries to map it to an internal user for authorization.